# incompatible type for argument 1 of `check'

Tags: c, incompatibletypeerror

I am facing a problem while compiling this code. Any solution would be much appreciated. The code is as follows :

```
   #include<stdio.h>

    typedef struct nx_string_t
            {
                char *buf;
                int number; 
            }nx_string_t;

    typedef struct nx_value_t
            {
               union
                {
                nx_string_t strng;
                };
            } nx_value_t;

            void func(nx_value_t *vale);
            void check(nx_value_t *str);
            void func(nx_value_t *vale)
            {
                 if(vale->strng.buf == NULL)
                 {
                      printf("its done"); 
                      check(vale->strng);   
                 }
            }
```

Comment: You havent mentioned `check` function definition

Comment: `check` isn't taking the `nx_string_t` you're trying to pass in. Anything else is fairly hard to guess from the included code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vale->strng` has type `nx_string_t`.  `check` expects a `nx_value_t*` so you need to pass  `vale` instead

```
check(vale);
```

Comment: Well, `void check(nx_value_t *str);` expects a `nx_value_t*`, not an `nx_string_t*`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Oops, thanks, I saw that the argument was named `str` and foolishly assumed that meant it was a string type.  I've edited my answer rather than deleting as it seems to have provided enough of a hint to enable the OP to solve his problem.